# Count number of occurrences of dictionary values as nested list based on a query

Tags: python, dictionary, count, nested-lists

I built this inverted index:

```
{
    'experiment': {'d1': [1, [0]], ..., 'd30': [2, [12, 40]], ..., 'd123': [3, [11, 45, 67]], ...}, 

    'studi': {'d1': [1, [1]], 'd2': [2, [0, 36]], ..., 'd207': [3, [19, 44, 59]], ...}

}
```

For example, the term `experiment` appears in document 1 one time at index zero, in document 30 two times at indices 12 and 40, etc. I am wondering how I could count the number of occurrences of each term in the dictionary based on a dictionary of queries that looks like this:

```
{
    'q1'  : ['similar', 'law', ..., 'speed', 'aircraft'],
    'q2'  : ['structur', 'aeroelast', ..., 'speed', 'aircraft'], 
    ...
    'q225': ['design', 'factor', ..., 'number', '5']
}
```

The desired output would look something like this:

```
{
    'q1'  : ['d51', 'd874', ..., 'd717'], 
    'q2'  : ['d51', 'd1147', ..., 'd14'],
    ...,
    'q225': ['d1313', 'd996', ..., 'd193']
}
```

With keys representing the query and values representing the documents that the query appeared in, and the list would be sorted in descending order of total term frequencies

Comment: I think you meant "the **list** would be sorted in descending order..."

Comment: @SargeATM ah yes sorry, that is correct

Comment: Please provide an example input and output that would be derived _from that example input_. It is not clear to me what you mean by "list would be sorted in ... total term frequencies". What should the location of e.g. `d1` in one of your output lists be dictated by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Map queries to document vectors

A document vector is a dict with items `(document, word_count)`. These vectors can be added together by summing the word count for matching document keys with a default word_count of 0.

##### CONVERT INDEX TO DOC VECTORS

```
full_index = {
    'experiment': {'d1': [1, [0]],  'd30': [2, [12, 40]],  'd123': [3, [11, 45, 67]] } ,
    'study': {'d1': [1, [1]], 'd2': [2, [0, 36]],  'd207': [3, [19, 44, 59]]}
}

def count_only(docs):
    return {d: occurences[0] for d, occurences in docs.items()}

doc_vector_index = {w: count_only(docs) for w, docs in full_index.items()}
```

##### MAP LIST OF QUERY WORDS TO LIST OF DOC VECTORS

```
for q, words in queries.items():
    vectors = [doc_vector_index[word] for word in words if word in doc_vector_index.keys()]
```

##### SUM DOC VECTORS AND SORT

```
def doc_vector_add(ldoc, rdoc):
    res = ldoc.copy()
    for doc, count in rdoc.items():
        res[doc] = ldoc.get(doc,0) + count
    return res

for q, words in queries.items():
    vectors = [doc_vector_index[word] for word in words if word in doc_vector_index.keys()]
    total_vector = dict(sorted(functools.reduce(doc_vector_add, vectors, {}).items(), 
        key=lambda item: item[1], 
        reverse=True))
    output[q] = list(total_vector.keys())
```

The summation of doc vectors is handled using reduce `functools.reduce(doc_vector_add, vectors, {})`. This produces the doc vector that is the sum of the individual vectors for each word in the query. `sorted` is used to sort the keys of the vector.

##### LIMIT TO TOP N DOCUMENTS

```
max_doc_limit = 10
output[q] = list(total_vector.keys())[:max_doc_limit]
```

Limiting the documents can be handled by slicing before assigning to the output.

##### ORDER BY COUNT DESC, DOC_ID ASC

```
sorted(...,key=lambda item: (item[1], -1*int(item[0][1:]),...)
```

We can change the sorting order of the output by changing the key function passed to `sorted`. We use a trick of multiplying the second element in the tuple by -1 to reverse the order from descending to ascending.

Comment: Hi Sarge, awesome! That's looking great. Very savvy work. I have one additional question: how could I limit the output to a certain maximum document threshold to limit the number of maximum documents retrieved?

Comment: @Julien added section on limiting the number of documents.

Comment: You're a lifesaver Sarge! Where can I go to learn how you came up with that answer? Or does that just take years of Pythoning?

Comment: Sarge, one more specification I forgot to include in the question:  If two documents tie for their total term frequencies, the document with a lower document number should be ranked higher; for example, if `d12` and `d100` have the same total term frequences for a given query, `d12` should be ranked higher than `d100` because `12 < 100`

Comment: @Julien added a section on changing the key argument in `sorted` to include document id

Comment: Sarge you're a real one. I wish I could give you 10 upvotes.